# How to pass Text instead of Value from select list to controller in Asp .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have two `<slect>` list and I want to pass only `Text` to the controller. I don't know if its possible.

This is Html :

```
 <form asp-action="Crea" method="post">
    <select asp-for="Azienda_cliente" class="select2 form-control" id="ddlClienti" onchange="LoadSottoCliente(value)"></select>
    <select asp-for="Azienda_sotto_clienti" class="select2 btn-block" id="ddlSottoClienti"></select>
    <input type="submit" value="Crea" class="w-50 btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

And this is controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Crea(Attiivita attivita)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Add(attivita);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Is it possible to post only Text from the select list?

Any suggestions how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @kvacka, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0):

> I have two `<select>` list and I want to pass only Text to the controller.

In your form, when you submit the form, the `Value` of the selected option would be posted to controller action method.

If you'd like to post `Text` of the selected option to controller action, you can try following two approaches:

**Approach 1**: populate your dropdown(s) with expected data as **Value** property.

```
<select asp-for="Azienda_cliente" asp-items="ViewBag.ClientItems" class="select2 form-control" id="ddlClienti" onchange="LoadSottoCliente(value)"></select>
```

*In action method*

```
ViewBag.ClientItems = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    //normally we populate Value property with Id etc field
    //in your code logic, you can populate it with your expected data (same as you set for Text property)

    new SelectListItem { Value = "ClientName", Text = "ClientName" },
    //...
    //other items
    };
```

For the second dynamic dropdown, you can set `Value` property with same data as `Text` of each `<option>`.

```
 $("select#ddlSottoClienti").append(`<option value="${text_here}">${text_here}</option>`);
```

**Approach 2**: you can get text of the selected option(s), then submit data using jQuery Ajax etc on JavaScript client side.

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function (ent) {
    ent.preventDefault();

    var Azienda_cliente = $("select#ddlCLienti option:selected").text();

    var Azienda_sotto_clienti = $("select#ddlSottoClienti option:selected").text();

    //make ajax request to your controller action
    //...

})
```